# Wordpress address where i can do simple php scripts with no output

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm wondering, wether it is possible to have some URL in WordPress, where there is no output, but it can handle my own functions. It has to have wp_head so that i can get things from WPdb and put things in wpdb.

What I need to handle:
 My client has a product database on their other server. This server every hour opens an url, giving changed products, so I can operate with them. All I ned is a static URL to tell this server to use this URL for exchanging the products. This address should call my own php function to operate with products.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply by creating a Page.

- Create a page within any name. Ex: **My custom page**.
- Save and publish it.
- Copy the slug, ex: **my-custom-page**.
- Create a PHP file on your theme folder named **page-my-custom-page.php**
- Now do you processing on the file **page-my-custom-page.php** as you like to send output.

Including wp_head, simple structure could be -

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <head>
> <title><?php wp_title('', '') ?></title>
> <?php wp_head(); ?>
> </head>
> <body>
>
>     <?php wp_footer(); ?> 
> </body>
> </html>
> ```